# How to generate "make:model -a" with directory for seeders and controller and migrate name?

Tags: factory, laravel-8, seed, tinker

### How to generate "make:model -a" with directory for seeders and controller and migrate name?

Laravel Framework 8.44.0

I am generating a model `php artisan make:model Blog/MyCategory -a` and expect to see the following structure:

```
Controllers/Blog/MyCategoryController.php
Models/Blog/MyCategory.php
factories/Blog/MyCategory.php
mifrations/2021_06_01_042639_create_blog_my_categories_table.php
seeders/Blog/MyCategorySeeder.php
```

Execute the command `php artisan make:model Blog/Category -a`

```
Model created successfully.
Factory created successfully.
Created Migration: 2021_06_01_044253_create_my_categories_table
Seeder created successfully.
Controller created successfully.
```

but it creates

```
Controllers/MyCategoryController.php (NO)
Models/Blog/MyCategory.php (YES)
factories/Blog/MyCategory.php (YES)
mifrations/2021_06_01_042639_create_my_categories_table.php (NO)
seeders/MyCategorySeeder.php (NO)
```

This way I cannot generate two `MyCategory`.

Execute the command `php artisan make:model Shop/MyCategory -a`

```
Model created successfully.
Factory created successfully.

   InvalidArgumentException 

  A CreateMyCategoriesTable class already exists.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/MigrationCreator.php:102
```

Remove the

- model `Shop/MyCategory.php`,
- factory `Shop/MyCategoryFactory.php`
- migration file `2021_06_01_044253_create_my_categories_table.php`

Now let's create the correct migration file

- `php artisan make:migration CreateBlogMyCategoryTable`

Again execute the command `php artisan make:model Shop/MyCategory -a`

```
Model created successfully.
Factory created successfully.
Created Migration: 2021_06_01_050039_create_my_categories_table
Seeder already exists!
Controller already exists!
```

It again creates a `2021_06_01_050039_create_my_categories_table` file and does not take into account the model in the `Shop` directory

Remove generated files again:

- model `Shop/MyCategory.php`
- factory `Shop/MyCategoryFactory.php`
- migration file `2021_06_01_050039_create_my_categories_table.php`
- controller `MyCategoryController.php`

Now let's create the correct migration and controllers:

- `php artisan make:migration CreateShopMyCategoryTable`
- `php artisan make:controller Blog/MyCategoryController`
- `php artisan make:controller Shop/MyCategoryController`

#### Total

Thus, we see that the "-а" option is not suitable in this case. You need to create models, controllers and migrations separately.

```
php artisan make:controller Blog/MyCategoryController -r
php artisan make:controller Shop/MyCategoryController -r
php artisan make:migration CreateBlogMyCategoryTable
php artisan make:migration CreateShopMyCategoryTable
```

Model with factory

```
php artisan make:model Blog/MyCategory -f
php artisan make:model Shop/MyCategory -f
```

This command also makes the correct `Factory`

`php artisan make:factory Blog\\MyCategoryFactory --model=Blog\\MyCategory`

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories\Blog;

use App\Models\Blog\MyCategory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class MyCategoryFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = MyCategory::class;
    
    // ....
}
```

The migration files, models, and controllers as we need in the appropriate directories.

```
php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
...
Migrating: 2021_06_01_055036_create_blog_my_category_table
Migrated:  2021_06_01_055036_create_blog_my_category_table (36.26ms)
Migrating: 2021_06_01_055541_create_shop_my_category_table
Migrated:  2021_06_01_055541_create_shop_my_category_table (39.16ms)
```

As I understand it, the required structure will still have to be done by separate commands.

But then another problem appeared: I do not understand how to use now `factory()->create()`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    \App\Models\Blog\MyCategory::factory(1)->create();
    return view('welcome');
});
```

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'larablog.my_categories' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `my_categories` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2021-06-01 06:59:52, 2021-06-01 06:59:52))
```

or tinker

```
php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.8 (PHP 7.4.18 — cli) by Justin Hileman

>>> MyCategory::factory()->create()
PHP Error:  Class 'MyCategory' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1

>>> Blog\MyCategory::factory()->create()
PHP Error:  Class 'Blog\MyCategory' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1

>>> \Blog\MyCategory::factory()->create()
PHP Error:  Class 'Blog\MyCategory' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1

>>> App\Models\Blog\MyCategory::factory()->create()
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'larablog.my_categories' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `my_categories` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2021-06-01 06:48:26, 2021-06-01 06:48:26))'

>>> \App\Models\Blog\MyCategory::factory()->create()
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'larablog.my_categories' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `my_categories` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2021-06-01 06:48:29, 2021-06-01 06:48:29))'
```

How to make such a structure work?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is necessary to clear the cache, this command worked in my project:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use php artisan make:model ModelName -mcr -a

it will create all that you need. migration, seeder, factory, controller and model

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did you understand what I wrote, or did you just send me the text from the documentation?

Comment: I want `Blog\Category` and `Shop\Category` models to be in their respective folders in `Blog` and `Sohp` in the `Models`. This happens when a model is created. When you create a model with the `-a` parameter, a controller and migration are also created:
`Controllers/CategoryController.php` and `mifrations/2021_06_01_042639_create_categories_table.php`
If I then create a `Shop\Category` model, we already have `Controllers/CategoryController.php` and `create_categories_table.php` and there will be an error.

Comment: That's what I wrote about, that it is logical to generate controller and migration with corresponding path: `Controllers\Blog\CategoryController.php`
`Controllers\Shop\CategoryController.php`
and migration
`create_blog_categories_table.php`
`create_shop_categories_table.php`
in each case. Otherwise why this `-a` parameter